# chartjs with local dates

Tags: date, localization, chart.js

The ticks in my xAxis in my current chart are in the correct format, but the wrong language. For example: **"22 July 21:00"**

I would like them to be localized like **"22 Heinäkuuta 21:00"**, but the "locale property" doesn't seem to change anything. Am i doing it wrong?

```
var config = { // my chart config
    type: 'line',
    data: { datasets: [] }, 
    options: { 
        parsing: false,
        normalized: true,
        animation: false,
        locale: "fi-FI", // my locale

        scales: {
            xAxis: {
                type: 'time',

                time: {
                    source: 'auto',
                    minUnit: 'hour',

                    displayFormats: {
                        minute: "dd MMMM HH:mm",
                        hour: "dd MMMM HH:mm",
                        day: "dd MMMM",
                        week: "dd MMMM",
                        month: "MMMM",
                        quarter: 'MMMM yyyy',
                        year: "yyyy",
                    }
                }
            },
        }, 
    }
}
```

I've read all of the document's i could find. but i can't make sense of this [locale documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/locale.html)

Comment: The locale property was added in V3, you are using V2 so it wont do anything, so you will need to update

Comment: I'm using Chartjs 3.4. @LeeLenalee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to give the locale to my **date library** which is **Luxon** for me:

```
luxon.Settings.defaultLocale = "fi";
```

Moment does it in a similar way but i haven't tested this:

```
moment.locale("fi");
```

[here is some more information on it](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/658)